# ThreadAbortException при вызове Response.End

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, исключения

Проблема в том, что метод `Response.End` вызывает исключение `ThreadAbortException`, которое мешает дебажить.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы не возникало данное исключение.

Метод `Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false)` продолжит дальнейшее выполнение кода, что не допустимо в моем случае так, как далее свалится `500-я` ошибка.

Как обойти эту ситуацию?

Как прервать дальнейшее выполнение кода при вызове метода `Response.Redirect("nextpage.aspx", false)`?

Answer (score 6):

Никак.

На момент вызова `Response.End` вы обычно достаточно глубоко в стеке вызова методов. Каждый из которых может что-то возвращать. Единственный способ выйти из метода, не возвращая при этом значение - вылететь с исключением.

Поэтому `Response.End` останавливает обработку запроса бросанием исключения, которое ловится выше по коду рантаймом, и превращается в редирект.

Т.е. вариантов у вас всего два:

- [Правильный] Аккуратно вернуть результат из всех методов, до самого контроллера. В контроллере вернуть `RedirectResult`.
- Заглушить ловлю исключений студией при отладке - снять чекбокс остановки на `ThreadAbortException` в Debug / Windows / Exceptions.

Первый вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. иначе редирект через `Response.Redirect` обеспечит вам трудноуловимые баги с "cannot redirect after http-headers sent" при случайном смешивании `Response.Redirect` и MVC-ного `RedirectResult`.

Comment: _"при случайном смешивании Response.Redirect и MVC-ного RedirectResult"_ - а что надо сделать, чтобы они смешались?

Comment: @Qwertiy использовать только RedirectResult. Они смешиваются обычно при Response.Redirect в основном коде + RedirectResult где-нибудь в фильтре, чаще всего - в фильтре обработки ошибок. И вместо нормального исключения в лог пишется "не смогло редиректнуть пользователя на страницу ошибки" :(

Comment: У меня в вопросе не было "не", но ты всё равно на него ответил :)